# How to get an unobfuscated client-secret for keycloak client-secret REST call

Tags: rest, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

When calling the [keycloak REST api](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/14.0/rest-api/index.html) (see below) the output value is a string of asterisks (stars) - is it possible to get this information in clear text?

```
  curl \
  --silent \
  --request GET \
  -H "Authorization: bearer <MYACCESSTOKEN>" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  "http://keycloakserver:8180/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/clients/<MYCLIENTID>/client-secret"
```

returns/output:

```
{"type":"secret","value":"**********"}
```

How can it be retrieved in a text (not stars) format?

The client is configured with:

- clientt protocol: openid-connect
- access type: confidential
- standard flow: enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to generate the secret. Either via Admin Console:

[image]

Or via keycloak REST api, in your case (using POST instead of GET):

```
 curl \
  --silent \
  --request POST \
  -H "Authorization: bearer <MYACCESSTOKEN>" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  "http://keycloakserver:8180/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/clients/<MYCLIENTID>/client-secret"
```